# Unable to create multi key indexing in liquibase changelog.json

Tags: mongodb, maven, liquibase, quarkus

I have tried to create a multi key indexing
eg: I have a document

```json
{
  "_id": 3,
  "item": "ijk",
  "stock": [
    {
      "size": "M",
      "color": "blue",
      "quantity": 15
    },
    {
      "size": "L",
      "color": "blue",
      "quantity": 100
    },
    {
      "size": "L",
      "color": "red",
      "quantity": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

and wanted to try the multikey indexing
`db.inventory.createIndex( { "stock.size": 1 } )` in the liquibase changelog.json
in index_changelog.json i gave

```json
{
  "createIndex": {
    "collectionName": "inventory",
    "keys": {
      "$rawJson": {
        "stock.size": 1
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "$rawJson": {
        "unique": true,
        "stock.size": "stock_size"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but its throwing the InvalidIndexSpecificationOption.
Could you please provide the correct format
expected to create a multi key index in mongo db

Comment: Please specify MongoDB's version.

Comment: 6.0.4 and mongodb compass is 1.35.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i gave the name attribute in option in the `createIndex` part then it got worked

```
{
  "createIndex": {
    "collectionName": "inventory",
    "keys": {
      "$rawJson": {
        "stock.size": 1
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "$rawJson": {
        "unique": true,
        "name": "stock_size"
      }
    }
  }
}
```